# Rails in place editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a rails inplace editor plugin or gem for modifying my rails application built in rails 2.3.11 with ruby version 1.8.7.

Please suggest any applicable gem or plugin or any alternate solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

Comment: I agree, its really simple to use and theres a railscast about this.

Comment: Hey Its cool for rails 3 and above, I found it difficult for rails 2.3.11 application...suggest any other option